# ReCaptcha timing out when on server, not on local

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, recaptcha

I am using ReCaptcha via this method: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=611

Everything works great on my local machine - there are no problems there.  When I upload it to the server, that is where the problem shows up.

I get the ReCaptcha image to render, but any time the request is sent, I get a timeout.

Markup:

```
...
<div class="editor-field">
    @ReCaptcha.GetHtml();
</div>

<p>
    <input type="submit" value="Create" />
</p>
...
```

Code:

```
...
if (!ReCaptcha.Validate(ReCaptchaValues.PrivateKey)) 
    throw new InvalidOperationException(Enporion.Localization.Properties.Resources.InvalidCaptcha);
...
```

Environment:

- IIS7
- Server 2008
- Asp.Net MVC 3 w/razor

Any idea what I am missing - please let me know if you need any more information on the setup, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your firewall settings. Make sure you allow port 80 outbound (not inbound).

Comment: Great suggestion - I suppose this is pretty obvious... I will get back to you tomorrow; thank you.

Comment: @naspinski did that solved the issue ?? unblocking worked ? what command ??

Comment: yes this worked - I don't remember exactly what I did - it was a loooong time ago.